# Call a method from one controller defined inside directive in another controller : AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive in which controller exists, where i have a function. I need to call that function from another controller.

Directive :

```
    angular.module('test.directives').directive("manageAccess", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: "template/test.html",
            controller: function($scope, $element, $http) {
                $scope.getRoles = function() {
                    console.log('hi');
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

$scope.getRoles method is the method i need to call from different controller.

Controller:

```
    angular.module("test.controllers").controller("testController", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getUsers = function() {
            // i need to call getRoles method here
        }
    });
```

How can i do that?

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
angular.module('test.directives').directive("manageAccess", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            scope: {getRoles: '='},
            templateUrl: "template/test.html",
            controller: function($scope, $element, $http) {
                $scope.getRoles = function() {
                    console.log('hi');
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

controller

```
angular.module("test.controllers").controller("testController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getUsers = function() {
        // i need to call getRoles method here
        $scope.getRoles() 
    }
});
```

in html

```
<manage-access get-roles="getRoles"></manage-access>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[AngularJS Service/Factory](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/)**

I put the `getRoles` function within the factory for the API which can be injected anywhere.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e5uL61bb/)**

```
var RolesModule = angular.module('UserRoles', []);

RolesModule.factory('RolesAPI', function() {
    return {
        getRoles: function() {
            this.roles = 'my roles';
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
});

angular.module("test.controllers",['UserRoles'])
.controller("testController",function($scope,$rootScope,RolesAPI, $http) {
        $scope.getUsers = function() {
           RolesAPI.getRoles();
        }
});

angular.module('test.directives',['UserRoles'])
.directive("manageAccess", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "template/test.html",
        controller: function($scope, $element, $http) {                   

        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If the function is not dependent on the directive elements, move that to a service pass it to both directive and the testcontroller.